# Structured references in charts disappear, why?

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I click on a chart, click on "select data" and then click on "edit data series". This popup appears:

[image]

I want to change this cell reference to a proper table reference. So I write a table reference into the data series:

[image]

Now I click on enter and don't get any error message. I am happy. BUT, when I click to edit the data series again, the structured reference has disappeared. Why?

[image]

The chart still adapts dynamically to the table as I filter the table. But when I delete and add rows to the table, the reference doesn't always follow. I imagine if I could get the structured reference to not disappear, the reference would always follow.

Is it possible to use structured references in charts and have then NOT disappear?

I use Excel 2013, Windows 8.1

Answer (score 3):

This question was discussed in the Mr excel forum, 2011.
After emailing with Microsoft project manager on charts it was concluded Microsoft have chosen not to include this feature.

Link to forum thread:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/mrexcels-products-books-cds-podcasts/541307-charts-using-excel-table-columns-data-source.html

Nils

Comment: Microsoft's decision is as stupid now (in 2023) as it was then (2011).